# Given a vector with integers from 0 to n, but not all included, how do I efficiently get the non-included integers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given a vector with integers from 0 to n, but not all included, how do I efficiently get the non-included integers?

For example if I have a vector with 1 2 3 5, I need to get the vector that contains 0 4.
But I need to do it very efficiently.

Comment: Sort then walk the container looking at the gaps

Comment: Yes the input vector is already sorted which is good thing. So you mean just use a for loop and fill in a vector with missing elements?

Comment: what is the task you want to acomplish with this efficient selection?

Comment: If it's sorted then this is trivially easy as dribeas suggests.  If not, you could choose between `O(N)` time and space cost and `O(N lg N)` time cost with no additional space required.

Comment: Making it sorted is too easy make it unsourced and the question is more interesting

Comment: @BenVoigt why can't you do it in O(n) space, I think you can

Comment: If it's sorted, then it's probably possible in `O(lg n + k)` where `k` is number of missing elements, using something similar to binary search.

Comment: @BenVoigt my mistake the way you worded it threw me off

Comment: @aaronman: I can see how that wording could be a little confusing, but there's only one grouping that makes sense.

Comment: @zch: My feeling is that it needs O(k lg n). Do you have a specific algorithm in mind?

Comment: @TonyK, you're right. I messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the vector is already sorted, this becomes trivial:

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,5};
vector<int> ret;
v.push_back(n+1); // this is to enforce a limit using less branches in the loop
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i <= n; ++i){
    int present = v[j++];
    while(i < present){
        ret.push_back(i++);
    }
}
return ret;
```

Additionally, if it **wasn't** sorted, you could either sort it and apply the above algorithm, or, if you know the range of `n`, and you can afford the extra memory, you could instead create an array of boolean (or a bitset) and mark the index corresponding to every element you encounter `(e.g. bitset[v[j++]] = true;)`, subsequently iterating from `0` to `n` and inserting into your vector every element whose bitset position has not been marked.

Comment: Looks like it's missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea presented here is that we know the number of missing items beforehand if we can assume sorted input without duplicate values.
Then it is possible to pre-allocate enough space to hold the missing values beforehand (no later dynamic allocation required). Then we can also exploit the possible shortcut when all missing values were found.

If the input vector is not sorted or contains duplicate values, a wrapper function can be used that establishes this precondition.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

inline std::vector<int> find_missing(std::vector<int> const & input) {
    // assuming non-empty, sorted input, no duplicates
    // number of items missing
    int n_missing = input.back() - input.size() + 1;
    // pre-allocate enough memory for missing values
    std::vector<int> result(n_missing);
    // iterate input vector with shortcut if all missing values were found
    auto input_it = input.begin();
    auto result_it = result.begin();
    for (int i = 0; result_it != result.end() && input_it != input.end(); ++i) {
        if (i < *input_it) (*result_it++) = i;
        else ++input_it;
    }
    return result;
}

// use this if the input vector is not sorted/unique
inline std::vector<int> find_missing_unordered(std::vector<int> const & input) {
    std::set<int> values(input.begin(), input.end());
    return find_missing(std::vector<int>(values.begin(), values.end()));
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input = {1,2,3,5,5,5,7};
    std::vector<int> result = find_missing_unordered(input);
    for (int i : result)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11 && ./a.out 
0 4 6
```